# How to check if database contains username and password?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code -

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysql_select_db("my_db");
$myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']);
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mypassword']);

echo $myusername . " " . $mypassword; 

$sql="SELECT id FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE username='" . $myusername . "' and password='" . $mypassword . "'";

$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
  $_SESSION["username"] = $myusername;
  $_SESSION["password"] = $mypassword;
  header("location:login_success.php");
} else {
  echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The Employee table contains
1 ADMIN PASS
as id username and password

If i enter it into the form and hit submit, it opens up this code which is check_login.php
I have echo'd the username and password to check if its correctly entered.
And it displays ADMIN PASS on screen. So the username and password is correctly entered that's for sure.

Now the only problem is "checking for username and password" inside the employee table. It doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: first of all you're mixing mysqli and mysql pick one or the other. then test your code again

Comment: Thanks Dave for quick response. It worked when i used only mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "my_db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "MySql Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username='$_POST[myusername]' && password='$_POST[mypassword]'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    if ($count==1)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['myusername'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['mypassword'];
        header("location: login_success.php");
        }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid username or password";
        }   

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```